# Bad performance with Java

Tags: debian, performance, java

I have a computer that was running Windows with a lot of big programas (like Adobe Fireworks, and many other stuff) and the computer performance was really good. I decided to format my computer (I didn't need all this programs because this computer had a different owner) and I installed Debian 8 Jessie (stable).

But since the first fresh installation, every program that needs Java to run (like NetBeans, Google Chrome, Atom (advanced text editor) or anyone) it starts consuming CPU progressively (checked via *top* command) until I have to reboot manually through the button (the computer is unusable, I can't open the menu and click on *Power off*).

I tried using different versions of Java (7 and 8) but nothing worked. Java 7 is installed through the official repositories and version-8 through Oracle downloads official site.

Any word of advice?

**EDIT 1: Java version information**

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    24 May  6  2014 default-java -> java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    20 Nov  7 01:58 java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 -> java-7-openjdk-amd64
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2439 Feb  7 21:22 .java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64.jinfo
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Jan 11 18:54 java-6-openjdk-amd64
drwxr-xr-x   8 root root  4096 Feb 21 11:10 java-7-openjdk-amd64
drwxr-xr-x   9 root root  4096 Feb  3 08:56 jdk-8-oracle-x64
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2531 Feb  2 10:16 .jdk-8-oracle-x64.jinfo
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Feb 21 11:12 openjdk-7
```

**Edit 2: Java performance**
Also I've noticed via *top* command that Java process also consumes a lot of CPU (more than 200%).

Comment: Please post additional information related to exact Java versions and operating system versions.

Comment: I have the same exact set-up at home and my computer flies.

Comment: `Bad performance with Java` might be true for Netbeans only. `Chrome` and Github's `Atom Editor` are not java apps!

Comment: Hi Michael. Then, how are Atom and Chrome powered? And another question, what have in common NetBeans, Chrome and Atom?

Comment: Atom is built on electron (which is C++/java*script*) and Chrome (C++) is not dependent on Java, but does run java*script*, it is important to remember that Java **is not** javascript... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java I suspect the problem lies in the JRE (or a program that is being run in the JRE) but your offender is unlikely to be Chrome or Atom.  Try booting the device and using `ps aux` check to make sure the JRE is not running, then start Chrome and watch `top` for the JRE firing up, repeat for Atom, I doubt they're the problem.

Comment: You have three different versions of java installed. Why? Do you need all of them? Which one does perform bad? Check carefully, using ps, the executable name to discover which one has high load.

Comment: there is thread about this subject here : [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/investigating_high_cpu_for_java_processes_on_linux_aix_hpux_solaris_windows_identifying_the_suspects?lang=en) or here [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811411/high-cpu-utilization-in-java-application-why)

Comment: How do you expect people to help if you do not provide any evidence, statistics, hardware configuration or whatever that would help identifying the root cause of your performance issue? The fact you blame java while two affected applications do not use java in the first place is also questionable, to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

One reason for slower performance is probably OpenJDK. You have almost certainly used Oracle Java on Windows, and you should try to use the same JDK in Debian as well.

I see you have Oracle JDK installed, but you say it didn't work. Have you tried to [install](https://wiki.debian.org/JavaPackage) it using `java-package`? Once you download the JDK, run:

```
sudo apt-get install java-package
make-jpkg jdk-*.tar.gz
sudo dpkg -i oracle-java*.deb
```

You may want to remove OpenJDK, or make sure Oracle Java is used by default via `update-alternatives`.